# Unexpected type due to template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, type-inference

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
   template<typename T>
    class VarArray
    {
       typedef T* iterator;
    };

    void get_setpoints()
    {
         VarArray<int>::iterator mirror_id;
         int id;
         *mirror_id = id;
    }
```

The type of `*mirror_id` is `int`. So far so good.

Now I am going to add 2 completely unrelated typedefs in the middle:

```
template<typename T>
class VarArray
{
   typedef T* iterator;
};

typedef int MySpecialType;
typedef VarArray<MySpecialType> bool_t;

void get_setpoints()
{
     VarArray<int>::iterator mirror_id;
     int id;
     *mirror_id = id;
}
```

Because of these extra typedefs the type of `*mirror_id` has suddenly been changed into `MySpecialType`, whereas I really would have expected it to be of type `int`. This appears to be the case for at least the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ compiler and the EDG C++ compiler.

The reason why I think this is scary is that some nested unknown include file might suddenly change the type of your variable into something else. You don't know it and if you know it is hard to figure out where it comes from.

So my question is, is this behavior according to the C++ standard? And if so, is it intentional?

Comment: Your example is a bit.. weird, `MySpecialType` is just an alias (*typedef*) for `int` - meaning that the two are equivalent (they both denote the type `int`). What exactly are you scared about?

Comment: I don't think it could change your type into anything else. Your `int` will stay `int`. How do you check your types?

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp. May be this is a bit of a special case. I want to write a coding standard rule that forbids conversion from and to "MySpecialType". Now I get a false positive for "*mirror_id = id;" because EDG thinks it converts an "int" into "MySpecialType".

Comment: @Rotislav. If I accidently type "*mirror_id = &id;", the Visual Studio compiler states "error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int *' to
'MySpecialType'". Really weird.

Answer (score 1):

There is no type change: `MySpecialType` is a type alias (synonim) for `int`. That's right: these two are the same type.

In your example, `mirror_id` is `VarArray<int>::iterator`, but also `MySpecialType*` and also `int*`. These are all the same types.

What's confusing you is MSVC++ not calling the type of variable with the same name as you did in your program (which is a bug of MSVC++ which should be fixed).

As far as I can see (from the comment) you expected so called "strong typedefs", which C++ doesn't support directly - you can put your `int` inside a struct, and then forward all the necessary operations.

```
class MySpecialType
{
    int wrapped_int;
public:
    MySpecialType(int a) : wrapped_int(a) { }
    explicit operator int() const { return wrapped_int; }
    int get() const { return wrapped_int; }
};
```

Comment: This is not my question. My question is whether this type change is according to the C++ standard.

Comment: @PaulJansen And your question is flawed because there is no type change. See the answer.